# Diminuir ifs (detalhes no "corpo")

Tags: python-3.x, if

Quero diminuir os ifs em um código antigo de uns 2 anos atrás (mesmo que não tenha tantos, quero diminuir mesmo assim), quero refazer ele (foi meu primeiro código), dei uma parada em Python então estou precisando uma ajuda, segue o código:

```
altura = float(input('Qual sua altura em metros? '))

imc = peso/altura**2
print(f'Seu imc é de {imc}')

if imc <= 18.5:
    print('Você é magro!')
elif 18.6 <= imc <= 24.9:
    print('Você tem o peso adequado!')
elif 25 <= imc <= 29.9:
    print('Você esta com sobrepeso..')
elif 30 <= imc <= 39.9:
elif imc >= 40:
    print('Você esta com obesidade grave....')
else:
    print('Você esta obeso....')
    print('Não conseguimos calcular o seu imc...')
```

Comment: Se o IMC der 18.51 vai cair no último `else`. De qualquer forma, não precisa testar desse jeito. Se não entrar no primeiro `if` é pq com certeza é maior que 18.5 e não precisa testar de novo no `elif` seguinte. O mesmo vale para os demais: https://ideone.com/L88Nw6

Answer (score 1):

Da forma como estabelece os intervalos comparativos você está gerando hiatos no domínio da comparação, veja a situação:

```python
       .
       .
       .
if imc <= 18.5:
    print('Você é magro!')
elif 18.6 <= imc <= 24.9:
       .
       .
       .
```

...se o `imc` for menor ou igual a `18.5` imprime algo, senão se `imc` for maior ou igual a `18.6` ao mesmo tempo que seja menor ou igual a `24.9`.... mas  se o `imc` for `18.55`?
`18.55` é maior que `18.5` porém é menor que `18.6`. Ou seja existe uma faixa de infinitos números no intervalo `]18.5, 18.6[` que não estão sendo comparados e caem diretamente para a expressão `else:`.
O mesmo é valido para os outros intervalos de comparações:

- `]24.9, 25[`
- `]29.9, 30[`
- `]39.9, 40[`

Juro que tentei não copiar, mas [aqui](https://ideone.com/L88Nw6) o [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) apresentou uma abordagem mais consistente, onde são feitas apenas comparações do `imc` com o limite superior de cada faixa de valores de imc:

```python
peso = 90 #int(input('Qual seu peso? (Se for um número exato por favor coloque 40.0 ou 65.0 etc)'))
altura = 1.90 #float(input('Qual sua altura em metros? '))

imc = peso/altura**2
print(f'Seu imc é de {imc}')

if imc <= 18.5:                                  #imcs menores ou iguais que 18.5
    print('Você é magro!')
elif imc <= 24.9:                                #imcs maiores que 18.5 e menores ou iguais que 24.9
    print('Você tem o peso adequado!')
elif imc <= 29.9:                                #imcs maiores que 24.9 e menores ou iguais que 29.9
    print('Você esta com sobrepeso...')
elif imc <= 39.9:                                #imcs maiores que 29.9 e menores ou iguais que 39.9
    print('Você passou o sobrepeso...')
else:                                            #imcs maiores que 39.9
    print('Você esta com obesidade grave....')

#Seu imc é de 24.930747922437675
#Você esta com sobrepeso...
```

Apenas por curiosidade o memo código usando o [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/) disponível a partir da versão *Python 3.10*.

```python
peso = 90 #int(input('Qual seu peso? (Se for um número exato por favor coloque 40.0 ou 65.0 etc)'))
altura = 1.90 #float(input('Qual sua altura em metros? '))

imc = peso/altura**2
print(f'Seu imc é de {imc}')
match imc:
    case i if i <= 18.5:
        print('Você é magro!')
    case i if i <= 24.9:
        print('Você tem o peso adequado!')
    case i if i <= 29.9:
        print('Você esta com sobrepeso...')
    case i if i <= 39.9:
        print('Você passou o sobrepeso...')
    case _:
        print('Você esta com obesidade grave....')

#Seu imc é de 24.930747922437675
#Você esta com sobrepeso...
```